# How to combine grid arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, grid, 2d, concatenation

So if I have one int[3][3] temp1 and an int[3][3] temp2, both filled up, how would I combine them to make one temp1and2[6][3]? What I'm trying to do is splice a grid array, where x is the array to be spliced and y is the column I want to remove. I tried

```
public static int[][] splice(int[][] x, int y){ 
    int[][] temp1 = new int[y][x[0].length];
    for(int i = 0; i < y; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < x[0].length; j++)
            temp1[i][j] = x[i][j];
    }
    int[][] temp2 = new int[x.length-y][x[0].length];
    for(int i = y; i < x.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < x[0].length; j++)
            temp2[i][j] = x[i][j];
    }
    int[][] temp1and2 = new int[temp1.length + temp2.length][x[0].length];
    System.arraycopy(temp1, 0, temp1and2, 0, temp1.length);
    System.arraycopy(temp2, 0, temp1and2, temp1.length, temp2.length);
    return temp1and2;
}
```

but that didn't work. I am getting the error:

`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2` on the temp2[i][j] = x[i][j]; line. 
So for example, temp1 and temp2 would both be would be:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

and the combined would be:

```
1 2 3 1 2 3 
4 5 6 4 5 6 
7 8 9 7 8 9
```

Comment: *"but that didn't work."* what does this mean exactly?

Comment: what's `x`? You code doesn't compile, please provide a verifiable example.

Comment: Yeah sorry. I just edited it with the error message

Comment: Note that 2D arrays are actually arrays of arrays and `System.arraycopy()` works on arrays (1d) only. Thus you'd have to call that multiple times per column/row anyways. However, your method would probably work better if you don't create the intermediate arrays but just iterate over `x` and skip column `y` while doing that.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i would do it by hand

```
//returns a new 2D array with temp1 stacked on top of temp2 or 
//  null if the arrays aren't the correct dimensions
public int[][] stackArrays(int[][] temp1, int[][] temp2)
{
    int [][] temp1n2 = null;

    if(temp1.length != 0 && temp1.length == temp2.length 
            && temp1[0].length == temp2[0].length)
    {
        //create the new array to hold both
        temp1n2 = new int[temp1.length + temp2.length][temp1[0].length];

        for(int i = 0; i < temp1.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < temp1[i].length; j++)
            {
                temp1n2[i][j] = temp1[i][j];
                temp1n2[i + temp1.length][j] = temp2[i][j];
            }
        }

    }
    return temp1n2;
}
```

The result of stackArrays(allZero2DArray, allOnes2DArray) gives the following 2D array:

```
000
000
000
111
111
111
```